# load end event on a baselayer

Tags: openlayers-2

can a loadend event be added on the baselayer? I made a code which would get all the loaded tiles but will be invoked when the map is finished loading all the tiles?

I tried using Events.register and Events.on but to no avail and i'm not sure anymore how I would be able to achieve it.

Comment: Layer objects do have a loadend event that you can hook into. Unfortunately, I think the feeling is that it's not reliable - it often seems to fire immediately rather than when you would expect it to.

Comment: i see. i noticed it here too when i tried to make a sample. was thinking here that if the loadend fired once it will immediately unregister the loadend event.

Comment: It doesn't unregister, although if you want it to you could unregister it in the event handler. Also, the event doesn't work with third-party layers like Google and Bing.

Comment: darn.. ok.. I guess I should look for another way to achieve it. thanks for the help @drunkenwagoner.